# Await fetch affects the event loop until I comment it

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, event-loop

I am currently studying the event loop that handles NodeJS synchronous and asynchronous functions. From what I understand, synchronous functions will be executed first, then the asynchronous functions. On the example below, the console logs execute synchronously until I remove the **await** from the "fetchAPI" function, then the synchronous functions will execute first in the "eventLoop" function and then the asynchronous ones. I am trying to understand why this behavior is happening. What am I missing?

```
const experiment = async () =>{

    const num = 1

    setTimeout(()=>console.log("Hello from timeout"),0)
    console.log(num)

    const fetchAPI = await fetch("https://xxxxxxxxxxxx").then(x=>{
        console.log("Hello from API")    
        return x.json()
    })

    console.log(fetchAPI.id)
    
    console.log("String")

    Promise.resolve().then(()=>console.log("In promise"))

}

experiment()
```

The API "https://xxxxxxxxxxxx" will return a random number(139 in the example below). The output for the previous function is:

```
1
Hello from timeout
Hello from API
139
String
In promise
```

Whenever I remove await from the function "fetchAPI", it will output:

```
1
undefined
String
In promise
Hello from timeout
Hello from API
```

Comment: `fetch` immediately returns a promise and then queues up as an asynchronous task. `await` takes a promise, waits for it to resolve, then unwraps the promise, returning its value. (There are other edge cases that are handled, but they're not relevant to your code.) Note that the only synchronous code here is the function assignment and the call `experiment()`. The `experiment` function is also running asynchronously.

Answer (score -1):

The `await` in front of the `fetch()` tells Javascript that you want to suspend execution of the containing function UNTIL the promise that `fetch()` returns fulfills.  That's why none of the code after the `fetch()` executes until after the `fetch()` is done.

If you remove the `await`, then the `fetch()` sends it's request and then immediately returns and the containing function continues to execute other statements.  When the `fetch()` finishes some time in the future, the promise that you've registered a `.then()` handler on will schedule that `.then()` handler to run via the event system when nothing else is running.

So, the `await` suspends further execution of the `experiment()` function until the `fetch().then()` promise fulfills.  Without the `await`, the `experiment()` function continues to run without waiting for the `fetch()` operation to complete.

The `setTimeout(fn, 0)` gets to run as soon as you let your code get back to the event loop.  When you use the `await fetch()`, that sends the interpreter back to the event loop and thus the timer gets to run quickly.

When you don't use the `await`, the rest of the `experiment()` function gets to execute before control returns back to the event loop so the timer callback is delayed until later.

The `Promise.resolve().then(()=>console.log("In promise"))` runs before the timer because promises that are ready to run their handlers are served before generic event loop things such as timers (you can think of promises as having higher priority if both are ready to run).

The `fetch().then()` doesn't get to run immediately because it has actual asynchronous work to do that takes actual time before it resolves its promise and is ready to run, whereas the `Promise.resolve().then(...)` resolves its promise immediately and thus is immediately ready to run.

**Note:** It's perfectly fine to attempt to understand all this, but 99% of the time, you should not rely on the minutiae of how the event loop prioritizes various things waiting to run.  If you want to control the sequence of operations, you should usually write your code to force things to execute in that sequence without relying on minute timing details of the event loop.

In modern code, the easy way to sequence multiple asynchronous things into a desired execution order it so make sure all the operations use promises (promisify any that don't already use promises) and then sequence things using either `await` or a `.then().then()` promise chain.  In general, `await` is easiest for sequencing asynchronous operations as it is simpler to do conditional branching among asynchronous operations and I find it's easier to implement whatever type of error handling you want, either central or per operation or some combination of the two.  If you do it this way with only promises, you won't have to worry about the event loop details.

Note, nodejs already has a version of `setTimeout()` that is promise based.

Comment: My concern is that I have learned that the Event Loop executes the synchronous code first and then the Asynchronous code. Once the code is transferred to the Event Loop, "promises" and "process.tick()" operations are first executed followed by "timer functions", "I/O functions", "Check functions" and "Closing functions". When I remove await, the log is just like I displayed, but if I leave it, it becomes confusing for me to understand. I still don't understand how the log output is so different with await than without. I read everything you posted and am still confused.

Comment: @joe - Please re-read the first three paragraphs of my answer as that's the best I know how to explain it.  With `await`, your function is suspended until the promise resolves.  Without `await`, the asynchronous operation is started and then your function keeps running.  That's the difference in the simplest terms possible.  The entire point of `await` is to suspend execution of your function until the promise fulfills.  That does not happen without the `await`.

Comment: I understand that the code suspends actions until it is completed, but it's as if it is behaving in a sequential way by just adding "await". Maybe I chose a bad example, but if the fetch would've taken 5 seconds, would the log output been the same?

Comment: @joe - Well, the point of `await` is to make it easier to sequence asynchronous things in a sequential fashion.  That's exactly why one uses it.  It completely SUSPENDS further execution of the function.  It doesn't stop the whole JS engine because at the point you hit your first `await`, the containing `async` function returns a promise and the caller continues to execute (getting an unfulfilled promise back from the `async` function).  Sometime later when the `async` function finishes executing, the promise it returned will get fulfilled.

Comment: What I was expecting is the fetch to be sent to the event loop as fetch is asynchronous and await is also asynchronous? I was also expecting the asynchronous console log output on the bottom part after removing "await". Am I to conclude that the function will behave in a sequential way if "await" is added?

Comment: @Joe - The one statement you use `await` will behave in a sequential way, suspending the execution of the function until the promise fulfills.  Don't know any other way to say that as I feel like I've now said the same thing three times.  Is there some part of "await suspends the execution of the function until the promise fulfills" that you don't understand?